# How to delete Managed Objects associated with another Managed Object

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I may have not asked correctly but basically I have two `Managed Object Subclass` one called `Folder` another for `Items` to create different shopping lists. Each `Folder` has many `Items` and each `Item` has one `Folder`.

The problem I am having is when I delete a `Folder` the `Items` associated with it are not also deleted there still hang around in the *persistent store*.

Does anybody know how I can I also delete the `Items` that have a *relationship* with the `Folder` upon deleting the `Folder` ?

**Folder:**

```
class Folder: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var arrayOfItems: [Items]
@NSManaged var date: NSDate
@NSManaged var title: String
@NSManaged var Items: NSSet 

}
```

**Items**

```
class Items: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var date: NSDate
@NSManaged var index: NSNumber
@NSManaged var item: String
@NSManaged var folder: Folder

}
```

**Deleting a folder:**

```
context.deleteObject(self.selectedNotebook)

// Save the context.
  do {
       try context.save()
     } catch {
       print("error saving")
     }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your data model file, select the relationship, and on the right side panel select the Delete Rule Cascade

Also, this [page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html) can help you understand core data better